# Query Exact Matches in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I am working on developing a web application feature that suggests prices for users based on previous orders in the database. I am using the MongoDB NoSQL database. Before I begin, I am trying to figure out the best way to set up the order object to return the correct results.

When a user places an order such as the following: `1 cheeseburger + 1 fry`, `McDonalds`, `12345 E. Street, MyTown, USA`... it should only return objects that are EXACT matches from the database.

For example, I would not want to receive an order that contained `1 cheeseburger + 1 fry + 1 shake`. I will be keeping running averages of the prices and counts for that exact order.

```
{
    restaurantAddress: "12345 E. Street, MyTown, USA",
    restaurantName: "McDonald's",
    orders: {
        { cheeseburger: 1, fries: 2 } 
                : {
                    sumPaid: 1444.55,
                    numTimesOrdered: 167,
                    avgPaid: 8.65  (gets recomputed w/ each new order)
                },
        { // repeat for each unique item config },
        { // another unique item (or items) }
}
```

Do you think this is a valid and efficient way to set up the document in MongoDB? Or should I be using multiple documents?

If this is valid, how can I query it to only return exact orders? I looked into `$eq` but it did not seem to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe we have solved the problem. The solution is to create a string that is unique for the order on the server side. For example, we will write a function that would transform the `1 cheeseburger + 2 fries` into `burger1fries2`. In order to keep consistency in the database, we will first sort the entries alphabetically, so we will always hit what we intended with the query. A similar order of `2 fries + 1 cheeseburger` would generate the string `burger1fries2` as well.